# Fancybox wont work on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have fancybox setup on my page and it works fine on the initial click however if I exit fancybox and click the link again nothing happens...No console errors or anything. I use jquery to append my body element with a JS script I get from a 3rd party, that 3rd party then is then able to populate a div called "ollWidget". Any help is appreciated, thanks!

JS

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
var scriptSet = false;
jQuery('.btn-availability').click(function(e) {
    if ( jQuery(window).width() > 600 ) {
        if ( scriptSet == false ) {
            jQuery.fancybox(jQuery('<div id="ollWidget"></div>').css({ 'height': '1125', 'width': '940' }));
jQuery('body').append("\x3Cscript language='javascript' src='script-that-gets-code-from-external-site-and-populates-the-ollWidget'>\x3C/script>");
jQuery('#ollWidget').show();
scriptSet = true;
        } else {
            jQuery('#ollWidget').remove();
        }
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
    }
});
});



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
```

Comment: I suspect because this line `jQuery('#ollWidget').remove()`

Comment: i ended up blowing fancybox away and just building my own modal.